# MySql: Sum in combination with inner joins - wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three different tables:

1. articles
2. import (many lines with many article numbers, purchase date and quantity purchased)
3. export (many lines with many article numbers, sales date and quantity sold)

I want to know for an specific article how many where imported and how many where exported and if possible the difference between, so that the result should look like this:

```
102123345, 500, -250, 250
```

I tried the following SQL query, but the sum is not correct. It is much higher and it seems to be that something is multiplied.

```
SELECT a.Article, b.Article, c.Article, SUM(b.Quantity) AS IMPORT, SUM(c.Quantity) AS EXPORT
FROM sagecl_Article a
INNER JOIN sagecl_import b 
ON a.Article = b.Article
INNER JOIN sagecl_export c 
ON b.Article = c.Article
WHERE a.Article = ?
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I tried a GROUP BY a.Article, but sum is still wrong

Comment: @P.Salmon - There is a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aggregating along two different dimensions.  One solution is to aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT a.Article, i.imports, e.exports,
       (COALESCE(i.imports, 0) - COALESCE(e.exports, 0)) as diff
FROM sagecl_Article a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.Article, SUM(i.Quantity) as imports
      FROM sagecl_import i
      GROUP BY i.Article
     ) i
     ON i.Article = a.Article LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT e.Article, SUM(e.Quantity) as exports
      FROM sagecl_export e
      GROUP BY e.Article
     ) e
     ON e.Article = a.Article
```

Comment: This produces in my case the following message: Unknown column 'i.Article' in 'field list'

Comment: It should be `GROUP BY e.Article` in the 2nd subquery. But IMHO it's too much work to get just one row (there is `WHERE a.Article = ?` in OP's query) - I'd go fo subqueries in SELECT.